# Relation between median and arithmetic mean

Tags: descriptive-statistics, median

The median of the numbers in a list is $x$, and the arithmetic mean of the numbers in the list is $\frac{x+1}2$.

Quantity $A = x$ and Quantity $B= \frac{x+1}2$

1. Quantity $A$ is greater.
2. Quantity $B$ is greater.
3. The two quantities are equal.
4. The relationship cannot be determined from the information given.

I think the answer is  option $4$ ; because there is no information on how the data is distributed and whether the data is skewed to the right or skewed to the left.
But I am not sure about this answer.‌‌

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: To settle the point, you just need to find data sets for which $x$ is the median, and $\frac {x+1}2$ the mean, and for which we sometimes have $x>\frac {x+1}2$ and sometimes $x<\frac {x+1}2$.  Work examples.  It should be easy to find a data set for which $x=\frac {x+1}2$...maybe start there.

Comment: Could you please better clarify the context and what exactly $x$ is? Thanks

Comment: @lulu Thanks, I have the same opinion.

Comment: @user Unfortunately, I do not know how to define the median more accurately‌‌.

Comment: A broader question might be:  given two real numbers, $m$ and $\mu$, find a data set with median $m$ and mean $\mu$.  I suggest trying to do this with data sets of exactly three numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the median can be smaller than, equal to, or bigger than the mean.

Option 4 is the required answer, with the aforementioned possibilities corresponding to $x<1,\;x=1$ and $x>1,$ respectively.

Comment: Thanks. I was a little confused because, if the data is arithmetically exponential, the "arithmetic mean" is equal to the (median) point of the data.

Comment: @Raha I'm not sure what an arithmetically exponential dataset means, but the point is that *in general*, Option 4 is correct (even if Option 3 is correct in certain cases and Option 2 is correct in certain other cases, etc).